# Realizing max function using squares and square roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a commercial software which doesn't seem to have a max() function. I vaguely recall that there was a way to find the maximum of two values using squares and square roots but my google searches were useless. Can anyone help me out?

And is there an easy way to apply this technique to more than two numbers.

Comment: Why not just write a function Max(a,b){ if (a>b) {return a;} else{return b;}} ?

Comment: does it have a min function ?

Comment: Does it have an absolute-value function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$ |x|=\sqrt{x^2}$$
$$\max\{0,x\} = \frac{x+|x|}{2}$$
$$\max\{x,y\}=x+\max\{0,y-x\}=\frac{x+y+|x-y|}{2} $$
and 
recursively 
$$ \max\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}=\max\{\max\{x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}\},x_n\}.$$
So, yes of all you have is squaring and square roots and addition and subtraction and division by $2$, then you can still write a max function.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. And I wrote a code to nest the function functions for me, because impossibly tedious to do by hand.

Answer (score 1):

To find the maximum of two values $a$ and $b$ using squares and square roots,

note that $\max(a,b)=\dfrac{a+b+|a-b|}2$ and $|a-b|=\sqrt{(a-b)^2}$,

and for more than two arguments note that $\max(a,b,c)=\max(\max(a,b),c),$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

A max function.

```
def max(a, b):
    if a == b:
        return a
    return a if a > b else b
```

Also in Python

```
def max(arr):
    max_val = (most negative number ) 
    for ele in arr:
        if ele > max_val:
           max_val = ele
    return max_val
```

Comment: I am not sure if the commercial software mentioned is python

Comment: nope - but if/else statement should be. Though, the last statement in the OP's problem makes the above not quite sufficient as well.